# Naming the number of the row in a data frame that contains a certain value

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I've done some thorough research and I am struggling with an attempt to find a function that will name the number of the row (in my data frame the rows don't contain numbers) that contains a certain value. In this case a number.

e.g. Call the data `frame = df`

I don't know how to show a little image of the data frame but say that in row 5, column 4 the value was '162', is there a function I could use that will end with the return being '5' or 'row 5'?

I have used `rowsums(df=="162")`
which gives a long line of the rows, if they contain the values there is a '1' under them, if not a '0' but I need a function that simply states the row.

I couldn't figure out how to correctly use the '`which`' function either.

Answer (score 0):

which(df$col4=='162')

I am assuming that col4 is the name of the column number 4